# trace which method initiated a call to the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, sql-server-2016

I am using redgate sql monitor and I would like to know where in the code an expensive query was generated by Entity Framework.

I implemented IDbCommandInterceptor and used method explained [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/657), but this has a serious performance impact making it unusable in a production environment.

Is there an easy way I can get the name of the method triggering the DB call, save it on the DbContext and retrieve it from the context via DbCommandInterceptionContext? I was thinking of making a .TraceSource method on the context and saving it that way, but then I would have to refactor A LOT of code. Are there any events I can catch to achieve the same or any other suggestions?

thanks for the input!

Comment: If the code doesn't do really complicated things with building queries dynamically and gluing together different parts based on conditions, you could simply take a look at the query and search for the salient parts in the source. The translation from LINQ to SQL isn't *completely* straightforward, but there's typically enough structural resemblance (i.e. if it includes a `GROUP BY` the LINQ query almost certainly has a `group .. by` / `.GroupBy`, the tables it queries map to entity collections, etc.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert well the code does do complicated stuff... queries are really build depending on certain business logic. if we search most likely we will find the query eventually, but the goal is to be able to identify them easy and fast